# AES-RSA-Hybrid - AES BadPaddingException when using on different computers

Tags: java, aes, java-8, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I'm getting an "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded" when using a client/server program on different computers.
It works, running both client and server on the same computer.
The server is running Debian 7, the computer OS X 10.10.1

Client:

```
    Socket socket;
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

    socket.setSoTimeout(10 * 1000);

    System.out.println("Encrypting...");

    RSA rsa = new RSA(new File("public.key"), Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
    AES aes = new AES(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);

    byte[] wrappedKey = rsa.wrap(aes.getKey());

    out.write(wrappedKey);

    int length = ByteBuffer.wrap(Utils.readBytes(in, 4)).getInt();

    aes.decrypt(Utils.readBytes(in, length)); // Here is the exception thrown
```

Server:

```
    RSA rsa = main.getRSAEncryption();
    SecretKey session = rsa.unwrap(Utils.readBytes(in, 256));

    AES aes = new AES(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, session);
    byte[] data = aes.encrypt(Utils.toByteArray(file));

    out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(data.length).array());
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
```

RSA and AES are own util classes. What they're doing should be clear.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm doing all right, that's not my problem. The code is working, using it on the same computer. But not when using it on different computers. That's the problem.

Comment: @Artjom he's sending the (nonce?) key to the server under RSA and the data back to the client under AES; that's unusual (and not very robust here) but correct. @Jofkos how big is your data and are you certain `Utils.readBytes` reads *all* of it? TCP generally breaks data more than about 1400 bytes into segments, and the receiving program has to recombine them.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ok, thanks. Now I understand how that is supposed to work.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The thing is, when i'm running both (client and server) on the same machine, it works. Why is that solution 'not very robust'? I'll try another readBytes method, it's probably that

Comment: On one machine your data just goes into the sockets library and comes back out, it doesn't get sent over the network and so doesn't (fully) implement TCP. My "robust" point is that you hardcode RSA-encrypted length at 256, which may in fact (need to) vary,  and similarly assume it fits in one transmission, which is *probably* safe (almost no one wants more than ~11kbit RSA) but not certainly; explicit length is cheap and safe.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeah, that's because i'm only using 256-RSA keys, so it's always 256 bytes long. But you're right, that's not flexible. Thank you for your tip with the readBytes method. That was the problem. Now i'm using `DataInputStream.readFully` and it's works. Thank you! Post it as answer if you want me to mark it as accepted :)